# Can I call a user defined function outside of a target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to know the following:

- **Q1**: Can I call a user-defined function outside of a target?
- **Q2**: Would the changes happen inside like exporting a variable would take effect?

```
DOT_ENV_FILE ?= $(CURDIR)/.env

define importEnvFile
    VARS = $(shell sed -ne 's/ *\#.*$$//; /./ s/=/?=/ p' ${1})
    $(foreach v,${VARS},$(eval export ${v}))
endef

$(call importEnvFile,$(DOT_ENV_FILE))
```

Answer (score 1):

**A1:** Yes, if you use the [`eval` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function):

```
define defThings
 SKY := blue
endef

$(eval $(call defThings))

$(info sky is $(SKY))
```

**A2:** Yes:

- `makefile`:

```
    define defThings
     export SKY := blue
    endef
    
    $(eval $(call defThings))
    
    delegate:
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.other
```

- `Makefile.other`:

```
    report:
        @echo sub-make reports sky is $(SKY)
```

The other complications of reading and parsing a file and iterating over a list can wait until you have this much working. When you implement a new functionality, keep it as simple as possible until you have it working.

Comment: A1 related: why doesn't it work if the following simple echo line is added to `defThings`: `echo Hello.`? The error reported is: "recipe commences before first target".

Comment: @Danijel: You are trying to execute a *shell* command outside of any rule.